# How do I know where "Program Files" are?

Tags: java

I'm working on a custom installer / launcher in pure Java. How can I tell the path to "Program Files" or its equivalent?

Comment: Why specify 'pure Java' if the installer only has to work on Windows?

Comment: Good point. I know it makes little sense on Linux, I don't know about Mac. Guess "home" is a safer bet there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling the following:

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
```

will give the path of the programfiles folder in Windows operating system.

Comment: From your "Program Files", I assumed you were working under Windows. Perhaps there is an equivalent environment variable under Mac or Linux. I don't know. getenv merely allows you to "query" environment variables.

Comment: @Konrad: it returns the contents of the environment variable `ProgramFiles` which is what you should use under Windows. Mac and Linux don't have this concept so even if there was a variable named `ProgramFiles` it would most probably mean something completely different on those operating systems

Comment: Linux doesn't have an equivalent of "Program Files" There are many locations an application can be installed.  It depends on what the application is for.

Comment: They don't exist on Linux but the equivalent could be `/opt`. I don't think they exist in Mac.

Comment: @Gio: `/opt` is *roughly* equivalent.